# Difference between cx_oracle.cursor in python and cursor in database

Tags: oracle11g, cursor, python-3.5, cx-oracle

Is there any difference between cursor in cx_oracle api which is used in python and cursor of plsql in database?
If there is a difference please elaborate on it.
I am using python 3.5 and oracle 11g database and eclipse ide to use api and connect.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

They both reference the same underlying concepts and methods. What you can do in the one you should be able to do in the other. There are limitations, of course, but these are due to the differences in the languages being used in each case. If you have a specific question, please update your question accordingly!

Comment: "Thanks" for the reply